# Having An Observer To Monitor Android Views

Tags: android, performance

How can I monitor multiple views in my Android application. The reason I'm interested in this, is cause, my app has a view that has lot of fields `EditTexts, Spinners, CheckBoxes, RadioButtons` and some `EditTexts` are hidden unless a particular `Spinner Item` is selected or a `Radio Button` is checked. All I want the observer to do is to check all fields are filled before the **submit** `Button` is enabled and if any `View` was **un-hidden** it must check if the Fields have been filled too. This is where I'm stuck on what to do: I have a four **boolean** checks that check for the four hidden **Views**, but then I don't want to write a long **if/else** statement. Thanks

Comment: I have used if/else-if to validate all the fields in my app.. hope you find a single handle all observer as it will be helpful for others including me, but i doubt something like this exist.

Comment: Yeah. If/else-if would surely do. And make the code voluminous and just kinda weird

Answer (score 2):

The following code will help you to check an unknown number of Views of different types contained in a single ViewGroup. In your case with just four views, I think you are likely prefer four 'if' clauses.

You could mark all Views which you want to check by adding a tag in the layout file:

```
 android:tag="CheckMe"
```

Tags don't have to be unique, so you can use the same tag for all Views.
In addition to that, give an id to the ViewGroup containing your Views (this could be a LinearLayout)

```
android:id="@+id/myLayout"
```

Then in your activity you can first get the ViewGroup

```
ViewGroup myLayout = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.mylayout);
```

and then cycle over the child Views:

```
for (int i = 0; i < myLayout.getChildCount(); i++)
{
    View v = myLayout.getChildAt(i); 
    if (v.getTag().toString().equals("CheckMe")
    {
         if (v instanceof EditText)
         { // do something
         }
         else if (v instanceof SomeOtherView)
         { // do something else
         }
    }
}
```